# Calculating the progress percentage

Tags: c#, .net, file, progress-bar

How I calculate the percentage of a file that is loading in loop?

For example:

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
Process process = Process.Start(p);
StreamReader sr = process.StandardOutput;
char[] buf = new char[256];
string line = string.Empty;
int count;

while ((count = sr.Read(buf, 0, 256)) > 0)
{
    line += new String(buf, 0, count);
    progressBar.Value = ???
}
```

`

How I do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry,the format box, is not displayed here.

Comment: Fixed syntax formatting. You can use the {} icon to enter code, and if it doesn't work right, you can add <!-- language: c# --> before the code. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'd need to know the eventual amount of output to expect - otherwise you have no way of giving a proportion of the output which has already been completed.

If you know it's going to be a certain size, you can use:

```
// *Don't* use string concatenation in a loop
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
int count;
while ((count = sr.Read(buf, 0, 256)) > 0)
{
    builder.Append(buf, 0, count);
    progressBar.Value = (100 * builder.Length) / totalSize;
}
```

This assumes a progress bar with a minimum of zero and a maximum of 100 - it also assumes that the overall length is less than `int.MaxValue` / 100. Another approach is simply to make the progress bar maximum value the overall length, and set the progress bar value to `builder.Length`.

You'll still need to know the overall length before you start though, otherwise you can't possibly give progress as a proportion.

Comment: +1 
thanks for your reply,was helpful for me too. 
but why don't use string concatenation in a loop?